# How to close\hide from popup form window in javascript?

Tags: javascript

`javascript:Element.hide($("div1"));` 
Is not working from popup form?

Comment: you might wanna at least accept answers of like say... 11 out of 11 of your questions?

Comment: How do I close the original window from the new/child/popup window? i have opened in: <div id='div1' style='position:absolute;display:none;'><divonclick='javascript:Element.hide($("1"));' align='right'>
<font color='white'><b>Close</b></font>
</div>
<iframe id='Iframe1' src='' frameBorder='no' ></iframe></div>

Answer (score 2):

Ensuring that you have JQuery included in your HTML header, try the following:

```
    javascript:$("#div1").hide();
```

I notice you missed the # for an id or . for a class reference.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <!--DVID=00002304-->
    <html>
        <head>
            <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="div1" style='position:absolute;display:none;'>
                <div onclick="$('#Iframe1').hide();" style="color:#FFF;font-weight:bold;float:right">
                    Close
                </div>
                <iframe id="Iframe1" src="" frameBorder="no" >
                    ... IFrame content goes here ...
                </iframe>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It works without # also only If i clock on div onclick. But i openned sample.aspx form in div1 as popup window using . i have close button in sample.aspx popup windown. How can i closed from sample.aspx popup windwon on button click ?  var elem = $("divReplacement");

Comment: Hello, if its a modal popup then try  onclick="$("#divReplacement").close();" If its a new browser popup window, then you can use onclick="window.close();" (although it may be disabled on some browsers)